# How can I install Naudio Nuget package in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

There is no Naudio version for my .net 4.5 project. I need to install it but it says

```
"Error      Could not install package 'NAudio 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."
```

Answer (score 2):

`NAudio 2.0.0` targets `.NET Standard 2.0`. which is not supported by `.NET 4.5`.

[.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

You have two options:

1. Change the target framework of you project to at least `.NET 4.6.1` but recommended version is `.NET 4.7.2`
2. Install `NAudio 1.10.0` instead of `2.0.0`. `NAudio 1.10.0` supports `.NET 3.5+`

Comment: 4.6.1 is not sufficient. 4.7.2 is marked as the minimal one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the previous version like by running this command in package manager console `Install-Package NAudio -Version 1.10.0`